# How can I create a rope like object, that can attach object on the bottom and they will both respond to force field

Tags: physics

So for my scene, I've created a lantern and I want to hang it on a rope so it will swang with a wind force field. So my idea is to create a long strip of plane and use cloth physics and pinpoint one end, and it seems alright, but I got no idea how to do the other end.

I've tried using physics constrain but I realize it will not move with the end of the rope so the lantern is just fixed in the space.:(
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to stick an object to the bottom of your rope? If so you can do it this way:

- Select your rope, go in *Edit* mode and select 2 or 3 of its bottom vertices.

[image]

- Back to *Object* mode, select the rope, then select the lantern object, then click <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Vertex (Triangle)* to parent the lantern to the vertices.

[image]

- If you play the animation the lantern should follow the swing of the rope.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! It works perfectly!